# Fix decimal places up to 5 and remove zeroes after 2 decimal places

Tags: php

I have a value in a PHP variable like this:

```
$var='2.533333345';
echo $var;
```

What I want is to delete all decimal points after 5 digits.

like now the value of the variable will be

```
$var='2.53333';
echo $var
```

also, if `$var ='2.500000000';`, I need only `$var = '2.50';`. I need to remove zeros after 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yeldho Paul I have made function related to this. Hope this will help you.

```
echo cleanNumber('2.533333345')."<br/>";

echo cleanNumber('2.500000000')."<br/>";


function cleanNumber($val){
  $val = floatval($val);

  if(strstr($val,".")){
      list($before_dot, $after_dot) = explode('.', $val);

      if(strlen($after_dot)==1){
          $val = $val."0";  
      }
      elseif(strlen($after_dot)>=6){
           $val = number_format($val, 5, '.', '');    
      }     


    }else{
      $val = $val.".00";
    }
  return $val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine. actually there is one issue with else part. i fixed that

Comment: @Yeldho Paul yes i miss the dot (.). rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use number_format function

```
$var  = number_format(2.533333345, 5)
```

In the first argument pass your number an in the second the number of decimal places.

This functions takes more useful argument that you can review in the php documentation here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Number format takes two arguements, the first bieng the number your formatting (or a variable containing that number). The second is the number of decimals to output. Any additional decimals will be removed.

To format a number for output, you'd use the following:

```
<?php
$var = 2.533333345;
echo number_format($var,5);
?>
```

This code will output:
2.53333

Comment: thanks for the reply. i need to avoid decimal zeroes after 2 digits

Comment: What you'd want in this case is number_format($var,2);

Comment: for example if i get value as 2.53300 i need to display as 2.533 and if valueis 2.50000 i need to display as 2.50

Comment: In that case you can simply use echo (float)$var;

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

First, trim off all the trailing zeroes.

```
$var = rtrim($var, '0');
```

Then, get the string after the decimal.

```
$decimal = explode('.', $var)[1];
```

Depending on how many non-zero digits are after the decimal, apply a different number format.

```
if (strlen($decimal) > 2) {
    // display five decimal places for numbers without trailing zeroes
    $var = number_format((float) $var, 5, '.', '');
} else {
    // display two decimal places for numbers with only zeroes past two places
    $var = number_format((float) $var, 2, '.', '');
}
```

Comment: thanks.its working fine.  is there any php function for do this

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there's really a built-in function for it. Since you want two different formats depending on the input, I think there has to be a little more to it.

Comment: Of course, if you need to do this repeatedly, you can wrap this code in a function.